# Java: change prefix namespace in SOAP 1.2

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I create a SOAP server, run my server and use SOAPUI my xml client is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://ama.gov.pt/services/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:messageRequest></messageRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I want this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://ama.gov.pt/services/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:messageRequest></messageRequest>          
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using Spring Framework with annotations to do this.

My code is basically:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "pt.ama.ws.server.MicroServicesService", targetNamespace = "http://ama.gov.pt/services/xsd")
@SchemaValidation
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class MicroServicesService extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
@WebMethod
    public MessageRequestResponse messageRequest(@WebParam(name = "messageRequest") MessageRequestProcessNumber messageRequest) {...}
```

Comment: may you post your WS configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Angelo.

Comment: Sadly you are using JAX-WS and I'm not a great expert of JAX-WS

Comment: By the way if you want to use spring-ws you can give a look here https://github.com/angeloimm/spring-ws-sample